# How to prevent setState changing input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events, antd

I am using ant design form and trying to prevent clearing input after I check a checkbox.

Here is the code :

```
this.state = {

  externalOptionsArray: [],

}

// onClick function

optionOnChange = (e, index, array) => {
        const { externalOptionsArray } = this.state

        let externalOptionCurrentState = externalOptionsArray

        externalOptionCurrentState[index].is_enabled = !externalOptionCurrentState[index].is_enabled;
        this.setState({
            externalOptionsArray: externalOptionCurrentState
        })
    }

// Components

<Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

    <FormContainerWithDescription
        direction="vertical"
        title="Product"
        description="Product Information">
        <FormItemRow>
            <Col span={24} style={colStyle}>
                <FormItem label={'Product name'} colon={false} style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
                    {getFieldDecorator('title', {
                        rules: [
                            { required: true, message: 'name is required' },
                        ],
                    })(<Input />)}
                </FormItem>
            </Col>
        </FormItemRow>

        <FormItemRow>
                <Col span={24} style={colStyle}>
                    <FormItem label={'external_options'} colon={ false } style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>   
                        { externalOptionsArray.map((option, index, array) => {
                            return (
                                <Col style={{ float: 'left', width: '50%' }} key={option.name}>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Checkbox defaultChecked={option.is_enabled} onChange={() => this.optionOnChange(index, array)}>{option.name}</Checkbox>
                                    </Row>
                                </Col>
                            )
                        })}
                    </FormItem>
                </Col>
            </FormItemRow>

    </FormContainerWithDescription>
</Form>
```

And here is the image for better understanding

[image: screen shot]

The problem is when I input a text in a input field and click one of checkboxes, input field automatically cleared up, it goes blank input field again.

I believe this is happening due to setState inside of **optionOnChange** function. Whenever I click one of checkboxes, setState takes place and it rerenders the DOM.

So I used **e.preventDefault()** and **e.stopPropagaion** inside of **Checkbox** component like this below.

```
<Checkbox defaultChecked={option.is_enabled} onChange={() => this.optionOnChange(index, array)} onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>{option.name}</Checkbox>

// and

optionOnChange = (e, index, array) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        const { externalOptionsArray } = this.state

        let externalOptionCurrentState = externalOptionsArray

        externalOptionCurrentState[index].is_enabled = !externalOptionCurrentState[index].is_enabled;
        this.setState({
            externalOptionsArray: externalOptionCurrentState
        })
    }
```

But neither of them work

How can I make Checkbox works without rerender the input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make it a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). If you set the value of the Input component using a state variable then it remains even after state change.

So looking at your code above, you may need to have another variable like *productName* in the state and a onChange event handler to set the state when the input is changed

```
this.state = {
 externalOptionsArray: [],
 productName: '',
}

onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({productName: e.target.value});
}
```

And pass this to the Input like

```
<Input value={this.state.productName} onChange={this.onChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store product's name in state and change it when input changes.

```
this.state = {
  externalOptionsArray: [],
  productName: '',
}
```

then define onChange function where you handle updating the state, like you did in optionOnChange()

and pass it to your Input component

```
<Input onChange={this.onChange} />
```